# Average acceleration when more than two different velocities occur

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration, vectors

> Suppose a car travels at 5m/s north for 5 seconds, it then turn east and travel at 7m/s for 10 seconds, finally it turns north east and travel at 10 m/s for 20 seconds. What is the average acceleration over these 35 seconds?

I know acceleration average is the change in velocity over the change in time. If there was just two vectors for velocity, then I would subtract those two vectorally. However, I don't know how to find the average acceleration from 3 or more vectors. Do I just subtract these 3 vectors vectorally and divide that the result by 35 seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you're confused about how to calculate some quantity, try going back to the *definition.*

Think carefully about what the definition of average acceleration is:

$$\vec a_\textrm{avg}\equiv\frac{\vec v_\textrm{final}-\vec v_\textrm{initial}}{\Delta t_\textrm{elapsed}}.$$

Which velocities does this equation depend on? Which velocities does it *not* depend on?

Comment: So I only have to vectorally subtract the 10m/s and the 5m/s?

Comment: I'll leave that for you to decide.

Comment: Say if I replaced the velocities with distances...5 meters north, 4 meters west, 10 meters northwest...and I want to find average velocity. I can't just do 10 meters minus 5 meters vectorally

Comment: True, because for average velocity you don't subtract displacements; you subtract positions.

Comment: There we go, that was it, thankyou so much for helping me! Now I get what's going on.

Comment: I would have not come to this answer, because I would not have used your definition of "average acceleration". Specifically I was worrying about the "infinite acceleration" at the points where the car is turning, and zero acceleration the rest of the way. This scenario is so unphysical I just get brain freeze...